# SAP BusinessObjects - Create a WHERE condition based on user prompt input

Tags: sql, business-objects

I have a report with a typical date column. I want the user to select a start date from @prompt. Then I want the end date to be 3 months less than the user selected start date.

Example:

```
SELECT Date,Y,Z
FROM TABLE
WHERE Table.Date  >=  @prompt('Enter value(s) for Acct Open Dt','D',Object',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0)
AND
Table.Date <= USER ENTERED DATE - 3 months
```

Is this possible? I have done this very easily in other reporting tools. It seems odd that BOBJ would not have this functionality.

Comment: check this out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT Date,Y,Z
FROM TABLE
WHERE Table.Date  >=  @prompt('Enter value(s) for Acct Open     Dt','D',Object',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0)
AND Table.Date BETWEEN userentereddate AND dateadd(m,-3,userentereddate)
```

Comment: There is no variable named user entered date. I just put that there as an example of what I needed there

Comment: Right, all you have to do is change that to your variable name.

Comment: BOBJ doesn't work like that. How would the user repsonse from the prompt be passed to that variable??

Answer (score 1):

you can create new objects in the universe
[promptDate] =  @prompt('Enter value(s) for Acct Open Dt','D',Object',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0)

[promptDatePlusThreeMonths] = dateadd(month, 3, [promptDate])

and add a condition in the report

WHERE Table.Date  between [promptDate] and [promptDatePlusThreeMonths]

Or just create a condition in the universe:

Table.Date between @prompt('Enter value(s) for Acct Open Dt','D',Object',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0) and dateadd(month, 3, @prompt('Enter value(s) for Acct Open Dt','D',Object',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0))